# fql select friends who don't like a particular facebook item

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

```
select first_name, last_name, uid from user where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me() and uid2 **not** in(SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE object_id={0}))
```

But the not is not recognised by facebook. How do you solve this issue?
without the not, you will get the list of all friends who like something

Answer (score 1):

Don't think there is a direct way to do this. You might need to do batch queries, one to get the uids of all your friends who have liked a particular object, and compare them against the list of friend-ids and eliminate the matches.